# Pandas won't recognise values in one of its columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that contains a column with data type object which is a list of IDs such as:

```
data = {'my_column': ['E02002559', 'E02002560', 'E02002561'],
         'some_vals': [2,3,4]}
my_df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

But when I try to find the data assigned to one one of the IDs with the following code:

```
my_df[my_column]=='E02002559'
```

It returns false.

I am trying to merge two data  frames based on the ID column but since it won't recognise the values I can't get the merge done. Does anybody have any ideas as to why this is happening?

I tried converting the object data type to string but it won't do it.

The merge I am trying to do:

```
other_data = {'my_column2': ['E02002559', 'E02002560', 'E02002561'],
         'some_vals2': [5,6,7]}
my_df2 = pd.DataFrame(other_data)

merged_df = my_df.merge(my_df2, left_on='my_column', right_on='my_column2'
```

Edited for clearness.

Comment: try `my_df[my_column == 'E02002559']`

Comment: Just going off what you posted my_column is used twice as array and as index, post the full code ot fix the mistakes.

Comment: Thank you Leo, it just returns all false

Comment: Could you write a minimal example containing both dataframes that you want to merge? I assume there are much easier ways to merge arrays than what you are trying to do, however at the moment it is hard to tell.

Comment: When I try `my_df['my_column']=='E02002559'` I get `True, False, False`.

Comment: Please provide a reproducible constructor for your dataframe. Assuming `df`, what is the output of: `df.to_dict()`?

Comment: Your `merge` is working fine, what is the expected output? Make sure you don't have leading/trailing spaces in the merging keys.

Comment: When I try your merge, the first row is `0  E02002559          2  E02002559           5`. What's wrong with that?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone, while I was following @mozway advice I saw that the IDs had a space after them which has solved my issue.

To clarify I did: `df.to_dict()` which showed me the extra space